# How to open a pdf file on a pop up window?

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

I have made a pdf viewer using tkinter. I am wondering if I can let the pdf file 'pop out' using `Toplevel()` function. I tried to use `lambda` to try to incorporate the `Toplevel()` when using the button but the pop out window did not reflect anything. Here is the code I made:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
import os 

#make tk case
root = Tk() 
root.geometry("1000x700+200+100")
root.title("PDF Viewer")
root.configure(bg="light blue")  

#view frame
view_frame=Frame(root, bg="light blue", bd=5, width=400)
view_frame.pack(side=LEFT)  

#to generate pop up window to view PDFs  
def popup(filename):  
    win=Toplevel()  
    win.geometry("100x80")  
    win.title(filename)  
    

v2=None 
file = ''
#search for files
def viewpdf():
#make v2 global
    global v2

    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                        title="Select PDF File",
                                        filetype=(("PDF File", ".pdf"),
                                                  ("PDF File", ".PDF"),
                                                  ("All File",".txt")))

    if filename:
        global file
        file=filename
        #destroy old file if it exists
        if v2:
            v2.destroy()
        #create new pdf images  
        v1=pdf.ShowPdf()
        #clear stored images
        v1.img_object_li.clear()
        #store new images
        v2=v1.pdf_view(view_frame, pdf_location=open(filename,"r"),height=50, width=80)
        v2.pack(pady=(0,0))

#set buttons
view_button=Button(view_frame, text='SEARCH FOR FILES', command=lambda: [viewpdf(), popup(file)], width=50, bd=5)
view_button.pack()  

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Have you tried to do it?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes I have tried, though the pop out window doesn't reflect anything. I have added my code and where I am stuck.

Comment: @MagnusO_O Thanks! I added my code now and where I am stuck. I guess I need to somehow connect my viewpdf() and my popup() so I tried to run them both on the same button

Comment: This code creates a new window, but doesn't put anything inside the window.  Since we know nothing about your pdb library, there's no way we can know how to add it to your window.

Comment: The `pdf_location` keyword argument expects the path of the file rather than the file object. Use `pdf_location=filename` rather than `pdf_location=open(filename,"r")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have tried adding `tkinter.TopLevel()` inside the `def viewpdf()` and it worked! I have deleted the `def popup()` as well.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf
import os 

#make tk case
root = Tk() 
root.geometry("1000x700+200+100")
root.title("PDF Viewer")
root.configure(bg="light blue")  

#view frame
view_frame=Frame(root, bg="light blue", bd=5, width=400)
view_frame.pack(side=LEFT)  


v2 = None
#search for files
def viewpdf():
    #make v2 global
    global v2

    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                        title="Select PDF File",
                                        filetype=(("PDF File", ".pdf"),
                                                  ("PDF File", ".PDF"),
                                              ("All File",".txt")))

    if filename:
        
        #destroy old file if it exists
        if v2:
            v2.destroy()
        #create new pdf images  
        v1=pdf.ShowPdf()
        #clear stored images
        v1.img_object_li.clear()
        #set a new pop out window
        newWindow=tkinter.Toplevel(view_frame)
        #store new images
        v2=v1.pdf_view(newWindow, pdf_location=filename, height=50, width=80)
        v2.pack(pady=(0,0))
```